# Boost iterator_facade dereference

Tags: c++, templates, boost, iterator

I'm trying to use boost iterator facade to implement an iterator for a class that stores a sorted vector of elements of type data_t. Currently I'm having troubles with dereferencing it. I only need the iterator for traversal and searching, the iterator doesn't need to change any of the internal state of the Range object.

Here's the range.hpp:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <functional>

#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

struct testRangeImpl{
    typedef unsigned int data_t;

    struct RangeOrdering : public std::binary_function< data_t const &, data_t const &, bool >{
        bool operator()(data_t const& a, data_t const& b){
            return a < b;
        }
    };
};


template<
    typename ImplT 
>
class SortedRange: public boost::iterator_facade< 
                    SortedRange< ImplT >,  //this type because of the CRTP
                    typename ImplT::data_t, //The type of the data
                    boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag //iterators can be incremented and decremented
                >{
    public:
        /*! this type */
        typedef SortedRange< ImplT > type;

        /*! The type of the implementation policy */
        typedef ImplT impl_t; 

        /*! The internal representation of an element */
        typedef typename impl_t::data_t data_t;

        /*! The internal representation of a range */
        typedef std::vector< data_t > range_t;

        /*! A member variabe to keep track of if the range has been sorted */
        bool m_sorted;

        /*! The actual range itself in its internal representation */
        range_t m_range;

        /*! The actual range itself in its internal representation */
        size_t m_range_size;

        /*! An exception indicating an invalid range */
        struct InvalidRangeException{};

        /*! Current element for iterator */
        size_t m_current_combo;

        enum class PositionClass {
            NOT_END,
            END,
            REND
        };

        explicit SortedRange( )
            : m_sorted(false), m_range(), m_range_size(0), m_current_combo(0) , m_posclass(PositionClass::END){
        }

        explicit SortedRange(std::vector < data_t > const& rg, size_t const& current_combo, PositionClass const& p )
            : m_sorted(false), m_range(rg), m_range_size(rg.size()), m_current_combo(current_combo) , m_posclass(p){
            if(rg.empty()){
                throw InvalidRangeException();
            }
            std::sort(m_range.begin(),m_range.end(),typename ImplT::RangeOrdering());
            m_sorted = true;
            //initialise();
        }

    protected:
        explicit SortedRange(std::vector < data_t > const& rg)
            : m_sorted(false), m_range(rg), m_range_size(rg.size()), m_current_combo(0) , m_posclass(PositionClass::NOT_END){
            if(rg.empty()){
                throw InvalidRangeException();
            }
            std::sort(m_range.begin(),m_range.end(),typename ImplT::RangeOrdering());
            m_sorted = true;
            //initialise();
        }   

        /*! Implementation policy object */
        impl_t m_impl;

        /*! construct a range with a specific internal state */
        explicit SortedRange(std::vector < data_t > const& rg, size_t const& current_combo)
            : m_sorted(false), m_range(rg), m_range_size(rg.size()), m_current_combo(current_combo) , m_posclass(PositionClass::NOT_END){
            if(rg.empty()){
                throw InvalidRangeException();
            }
            std::sort(m_range.begin(),m_range.end(),typename ImplT::RangeOrdering());
            m_sorted = true;
            //initialise();
        }
    public:

        size_t size(){
            m_range_size = m_range.size();
            return m_range_size;
        }

        /* Return first data */
        type begin() const {
            return type(m_range, 0);
        }

        type end() const {
            return type(m_range, m_current_combo, PositionClass::END);
        }

        type rend() const {
            return type(m_range, m_current_combo, PositionClass::REND);
        }

        /* Return last data */
        type rbegin() const {
            return type(m_range, m_range_size -1 );
        }

    private:
        friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

        /*! Position class */
        PositionClass m_posclass;

        /*! set up the initial state */
        void initialise() {
            std::sort(m_range.begin(),m_range.end());
            m_sorted == true;
        }

        /*! the first element */
        data_t first() const {
            return m_range[0];
        }

        /*! the last element */
        data_t last() const {
            return m_range[m_range_size - 1];
        }


        /*! return the current element */
        const data_t& dereference() const  {
            if(m_posclass == PositionClass::NOT_END) {
                return m_range[m_current_combo];
            }else {
                throw std::out_of_range("Attempt to dereference past the valid range");
            }
        }

        /*! get the next combination */
        void increment() {
            if(m_posclass != PositionClass::NOT_END)
                throw std::out_of_range("Cannot increment past the valid range");

            if(m_current_combo == m_range_size ) {
                //current combination is the last
                m_posclass = PositionClass::END;
            }
            m_current_combo++;
        }

        /*! get the previous combination */
        void decrement() {
            if(m_posclass != PositionClass::NOT_END)
                throw std::out_of_range("Cannot decrement past the valid range");

            if(m_current_combo == 0) {
                //current combination is the first
                m_posclass = PositionClass::REND;
            }
            m_current_combo--;  
        }

        /*! check for equality between two iterators. */
        bool equal(type const& other) const {
           if(m_posclass == PositionClass::NOT_END && 
           other.m_posclass == PositionClass::NOT_END) {

               return 
                   m_current_combo == other.m_current_combo &&
                   m_range == other.m_range;
           }
           else {
                return m_posclass == other.m_posclass && m_range == other.m_range;
           }
        }
};

struct Range : public SortedRange< testRangeImpl>{
    /*! An exception we throw if someone tries to construct an invalid range */
    struct InvalidRangeException : public SortedRange< testRangeImpl >::InvalidRangeException {};

    /*! Construct a range from a vector of unsigned ints */
    explicit Range(std::vector<unsigned int> const& r) : SortedRange<testRangeImpl>(r)
    {
        if(r.empty()){
            throw InvalidRangeException();
        }
    }
};
```

Here's the main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "range.hpp"
int main(void){
    std::vector<unsigned int> rg  = { 2 , 5 , 1 , 3 , 4 };
    Range test(rg);
    for(auto elem: test){
        std::cout << elem << " " ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling gives this error:

```
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp: In static member function ‘static typename Facade::reference boost::iterator_core_access::dereference(const Facade&) [with Facade = SortedRange<testRangeImpl>, typename Facade::reference = unsigned int&]’:
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:643:67:   instantiated from ‘boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::reference boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::operator*() const [with Derived = SortedRange<testRangeImpl>, Value = unsigned int, CategoryOrTraversal = boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, Reference = unsigned int&, Difference = long int, boost::iterator_facade<I, V, TC, R, D>::reference = unsigned int&]’
main.cpp:9:17:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:517:32: error: invalid initialisation of reference of type ‘boost::iterator_facade<SortedRange<testRangeImpl>, unsigned int, boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag, unsigned int&, long int>::reference {aka unsigned int&}’ from expression of type ‘const data_t {aka const unsigned int}’
```

How do I get this to be a usable iterator type?

Comment: You seem to be implementing a container and an iterator as one and the same class! - You might just as well use `vector::(const_)iterator` as your iterator type.

Comment: @UncleBens, is this considered a bad idea doing both at once?

Comment: Firstly I think it has a huge performance impact. Normally iterators are used as light-weight value objects. `auto it = range.begin();` makes a copy of the range!? Secondly it makes the implementation way more complicated. Have you tested that your reverse iterators actually work? I suspect not since I cannot see how one and the same type could be both normal and reverse iterator without any extra logic. Also note that to test equality of iterators you are comparing vector contents?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to take a non-const reference to a const value. For some reason you have decided that `dereference` returns a const reference, instead of honoring the facade reference type. Fix that, and it should work.